# I want to give widh to my layout grids

Tags: html, css

I am trying to give width to the second column but i am unable to do it. 
Any help is appreciable. The code is Below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<style>
.ui-block-a {
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}
.ui-block-b {
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Customized Columns</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Three-column Styled Layout:</p>
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
      <div class="ui-block-a"><span>First Column</span></div>
      <div class="ui-block-b"><span>Second Column</span></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

I am able to change the height of the columns but i am unable to change the width of it is there any thing i am missing? Please help. 
Thank you.

Comment: It is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/2av2ny1d/. what is the problem? which one you could not able to give width

Comment: Please provide entire css code or at least css classes that are mention in above HTML code

Comment: @ketan i want a one row and two column and the second column must have bigger width then second

Comment: @ketan yes I want that thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: table-cell;` for both the div and set the width of second div like: `width: 800px;` it will solved your issue.

```
.ui-block-a {
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    display: table-cell;
}
.ui-block-b {
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 800px;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Check [Updated Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/kyj5ov1b/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css

**CSS**

```
.ui-content .ui-block-b {
  width: 276px;  /*custom width*/
}
```

Comment: yes I applied your answer but there is no changes in it

Comment: can u give !important and check

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

[WORKING : DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/411kfrw6/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Customized Columns</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Three-column Styled Layout:</p>
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
      <div class="ui-block-a"><span>First Column</span></div>
      <div class="ui-block-b"><span>Second Column</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body,html,ui-content
{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
.ui-content
{
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.ui-block-a, .ui-block-b {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width:40%; /*You can choice as per your requirement */
    padding-top:50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.ui-block-b {
    width:59.5%; /*You can choice as per your requirement */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css  apply 
    `width: 33.333%;` 
to both the classes(ui-block-a & ui-block-a), If u want to make custom width then you have put 
`width: xxxpx !important;`.